# Getting generic parameter type name in F#

Tags: asp.net-core, f#

I have such classes:

```
type IInterface = {}

type BaseClass<'Data, 'TMeta> =
{
    Data : 'Data
    Meta : 'TMeta
}
interface IInterface with
    ...

type Record = {
    Value: string
}

type MyType = BaseClass<Record, unit>
```

Now in my .Net Core application I have an extension to make some registration stuff:

```
[<Extensio>]
static member Register<'t when 't :> IInterface>(...) =
   services.AddSingleton<Configuration<'t>>()

services.Register<MyType>()
```

And in my configuration

```
type Configuration<'t when 't :> IInterface> ()
    let tp = typedefof<'t>.GetGenericArguments()
    ...
```

I can't access generic arguments in runtime as they are treated as `System.Runtime`, while I expect to have an access to `MyType`

Comment: What is `services.AddSingleton` and `services.Register` ?

Comment: @TomasPetricek it's a Asp `IServiceCollection`